# between March 22 and June 6, 2021 vs. between March 22 to June 6, 2021

Tags: prepositions

> We conducted a prospective cohort study involving patients with suspected VITT who presented to hospitals in the United Kingdom **between March 22 and June 6, 2021**. Data were collected with the use of an anonymized electronic form, and cases were identified as definite or probable VITT according to prespecified criteria.

Source: [New England Journal of Medicine](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa2109908?query=featured_home)

(Note: The access to the link might be blocked in your country)

Are "between March 22 and June 6, 2021" and "between March 22 to June 6, 2021" interchangeable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really (though there is little chance of misunderstanding.

Idiomatically it is

> From ... to ...

> Between ... and  ....